# Assignment method with mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a question about Mockito library. I try to write some tests with it, but it doesn't work like I want. My idea was to test class test. And if the `getResult()` method is called, the result should be assigned to the variable res.

I tested the method that doesn't call `getResult()`, so, as I thought, the variable res should be un-initialized.

But the info-logging "makingres" appears when @Before-init() is being implemented, so the res has non-null value in any case.

Could you, please help me and say, what have I done wrong. Sorry in advance for some code misprints, if there are any.

```
public class Test{

     ResultClass res;

     TestedClass test;

     @Before
     public init(){

         Mockito.doReturn(makeRes1()).when(test).getResult(Mockito.eq(Argument.VALUE)); 

         Mockito.when(test.getResult(Mockito.eq(Argument.VALUE))).thenReturn(makeRes1());

     }

     Result makeRes1(){
        log.info("makingres");
        Result r = new Result(Argument.VALUE);
        res = r;
        return r;
     }


    @Test
    public test(){
    test.goWithoutResult();
    Assert.assertEquals(res,null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `makeRes1` is being called but you do not know why?

```
Mockito.doReturn(makeRes1()).when(test).getResult(Mockito.eq(Argument.VALUE));
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Result result = makeRes1();
Mockito.doReturn(result).when(test).getResult(Mockito.eq(Argument.VALUE));
```

Is it clearer now what is wrong? `makeRes1()` is called always in that `@Before` method and not only `when(test).getResult(...)`.

How about a `thenAnswer`:

```
Mockito.when(test)
       .getResult(Mockito.eq(Argument.VALUE))
       .thenAnswer(
          new Answer<Result>() {
              Result answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                  return makeRes1();
              }
        });
```

This delays the execution of `makeRes1()` until `getResult` is called.

**But** if you are only doing this to check whether `getResult` was called or not this is not the best approach (relying on a side effect), that is what the `verify` methods are for:

```
verify(test, never()).getResult();
```

Comment: oh, thanks!
I tired to implement when-then strategy (like in edited example), and makeRes1 is called in any case.

Comment: I do not understand why you would mock the object you are testing.

Comment: Your first few paragraphs are a good explanation of what the OP's code is doing, but your last few are a very bad suggestion for how to fix it. Rather than using `doAnswer` to generate a side-effect to record the call for later verification, (s)he should use `verify` -- or, more specifically, `verifyZeroInteractions`.

Comment: @ruakh I assumed that these are not real tests, just the OP getting their head around mockito. I thought they have merely provided an SSCCE for their problem that failed proving their `makeRes1` was getting called.

Comment: @ruakh Note the `verify(test, never()).getResult();` would pass in their current test, but `makeRes1` would still be called.

Comment: @weston: I see what you're saying, but I disagree. It sounds to me, based on the question -- especially the "I tested the method that doesn't call `getResult()`, so, as I thought, the variable res should be un-initialized" part -- that the OP is trying to use `makeResult()` to *detect* whether `gatResult()` was called.